# IOS: Facebook sharing dialogue dismiss Issue with pageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am using following code for sharing on Facebook. But sharing dialogue dismiss after few seconds. This issue i am getting with `PageViewController`. Its working fine if i am pushing without `pageViewController`.

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
                let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
                fbShare.addURL(NSURL(string:newsShareURL + "\(self.news.newsId)"))
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                    self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }


            }
```

Comment: What is the reason for the dispatch_async? I'd  simply use the line "[self.presentViewController(fbshare, animated: false, completion: nil)]" to have the dialogue appear, with the user then having the option to Cancel or Post.

Comment: Thanks for reply...I have done without dispatch_async as well,But was getting the same issue. let me tell you, i am getting this issue with iOS version greater than 8.

Comment: From reading up on what a PageViewController does, it seems that creating a dialogue box for sharing doesn't fit well with the page-by-page concept. You might have to leave the paging sequence behind entirely in order to create such a dialog box.